# Question about John Lee's proof of Proposition 3.13 in ISM on the identification of the tangent space of a vector space $V$ to $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I have a question about the proof of Proposition 3.13 from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.

[image]

We give $V$ the natural smooth structure given by the following Example.

[image]

[image]

Now the proposition is as follows:

[image]

It says we can use the same argument as in the proof of Proposition 3.2, to show that $D_v|_a$ is an isomorphism. I can see that the exact same argument applies to show injectivity. However, I do not understand how we can show surjectivity, as in the proof below, this requires using Taylor's theorem. However, Taylor's theorem does not apply here as $f$ is a smooth function from a vector space $V$ that may not be the Euclidean space. So how can we adapt the proof for a general finite-dimensional vector space $V$ here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: First note that the claim is not that $D_v|_a$ is an isomorphism -- the claim is that the map that sends $v$ to $D_v|_a$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: To address your question about surjectivity, the key phrase is "once we choose a basis for $V$." This allows us to write the coordinate representation of $f$ as a function of $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$, and it is this function to which you apply Taylor's theorem.

Comment: @JackLee I think the argument is something like this: We fix basis $(E_1, \dots, E_n)$ and let $E:\mathbb{R}^n \to V$ be the inverse of the chart that takes $Ex = x^i E_i$. As in the proof of Proposition 3.2, we define $v = v^i E_i$ where $v^i = w(x^i)$ where $x^i$ is the $i$th coordinate map. Now we need to apply Taylor, and we can do this on $f \circ E$ and get the same formula as in 3.2. However, we cannot take $w$ on both sides because $f\circ E$ is not in $C^\infty(V)$ but in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. How can we deal with this issue?

Comment: This is one of those cases in which the same symbol $f$ is being used both for the abstract function from $M$ to $\mathbb R$ and its coordinate representation $f\circ E$, which is a function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$. See the discussions on pp. 15-16 and 33-34. It takes a little getting used to, but ultimately you have to learn to think this way in order to avoid getting overwhelmed with notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this question is a bit old but I've managed to find a way.

I'll use the same notations as in the OP.
Let $(V,E^{-1})$ be the chart and $E^{-1} = (x^1, \ldots ,x^n)$ the coordinate maps. Your choice of the vector $v \in V$ is the right one, indeed take $v = w(x^i) \, E_i$ where $(E_1, \ldots ,E_n)$ is the basis associated with $E$ and $w \in T_aV$ is given.

Now, for any $f \in C^\infty(V)$ holds $ w(f) = (d(E^{-1})_a (w))(f \circ E)$ because $E \in C^\infty$ and we applied the definition of differential. You can now use Taylor's theorem, as in the proposition 3.2 of Lee's book, on $f \circ E \in  C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ at the point $E^{-1}(a)$ to get

$$ (f \circ E)(x) = f(a) + \frac{\partial (f \circ E)}{\partial e^i}|_{E^{-1}(a)} \, (e^i(x)-x^i(a)) \, + \sum_{i,j}... $$

where $e^i$ are the coordinate maps of the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (to not get confused with $x^i$).

So we have
\begin{align}
w(f) &= \frac{\partial (f \circ E)}{\partial e^i}|_{E^{-1}(a)} \, (d(E^{-1})_a (w))(e^i) = \frac{\partial (f \circ E)}{\partial e^i}|_{E^{-1}(a)} \, w(x^i) =\\
&= \frac{\partial (f \circ E)}{\partial e^i}|_{E^{-1}(a)} \, (E^{-1}(v))^i = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} (f \circ E)(E^{-1}(a)+tE^{-1}(v)) = \\
&= \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} f(a + tv) = D_v|_a f
\end{align}

Notice that we exploited the linearity of $E^{-1}$ to use the chain rule for maps $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, after we expressed $f = (f \circ E) \circ E^{-1}$.